# Meteor file upload error on heroku - Storage name already exists: "_tempstore"

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, amazon-s3

All file upload function is working as expected on my local development environment but when i have deploy my app to heroku it start giving error. i have reset database couple of time but still geting same error.
error :

```
    PUT ...................... 503 (Service Unavailable)
"Queue" failed [503] Error in method "/cfs/files/:value/:value/", Error: Error: Storage name already exists: "_tempstore"
```

can some on help what issue with S3 file upload from heroku..

i am using buildpack:  https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git

for s3 file upload i have used below packages.

```
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:s3
cfs:gridfs@=0.0.31
cfs:ui
cfs:graphicsmagick
```

Comment: Might be related to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/591).

Comment: Yes might be but any workarround to move further ?